# How to edit global file installation

Tags: node.js, terminal, directory, command, command-line-interface

I just ran this line of code

```
npm install -g csslint
```

CSSlint seems great but I want to add the ability to prettify my css by putting in custom code. The goal is to have a command line interface where I can format my css before pushing the code to the server.

"-g" stand for installing globally correct?

Where does this library get installed to and how do I access it? I thought it would be in my user/local/bin but I couldn't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use `npm root -g` to see where modules get installed. If you want to use it in your code using `require()` then install it locally i.e. without using `-g` option. More details here https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's going to depend on your npm settings, but my global npm binaries are in `/usr/local/share/npm/bin`